# innerHTML is not adding when submitting email validation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to manipulate the DOM if someone has put in the incorrect email into my form.  What happens is that nothing seems to happen on the page.  Below is my code for html.

```js
function ValidateEmail(inputText) {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    alert("You have entered a correct email addresss")
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("addedText").innerHTML += " this has just been added";
    // alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="email-entry desktop-container">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <form name="form1" action="#">
    <input id="test" type="text" name="text1" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="image" value="validate" onclick="ValidateEmail(document.form1.text1)" src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="submit">
    <p id="addedText"></p>
  </form>

</div>
```

When I put add an alert it seems to work.  Not sure what I am doing wrong in targeting the element.

Comment: You do not cancel the click. You return false, but the onclick does not return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the image, it acts like a submit button and submit the form. You do not cancel the click. You are missing return on the click so the `return false` is ignored.

```js
function ValidateEmail(inputText) {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (inputText.value.match(mailformat)) {
    alert("You have entered a correct email addresss")
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("addedText").innerHTML += " this has just been added";
    // alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    document.form1.text1.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="email-entry desktop-container">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <form name="form1" action="#">
    <input id="test" type="text" name="text1" value="" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="image" value="validate" onclick="return ValidateEmail(document.form1.text1)" src="images/icon-arrow.svg" alt="submit">
    <p id="addedText"></p>
  </form>
```